# Waiting for fork children to write to the pipe before continuing

Tags: c, concurrency, fork

Learning about `fork()` and `pipe()` for C.

The below code creates a pipe and a child process. The child sends a message and the parent reads it.

```
int main () {
    int     fd[2];
    pid_t   pid;
    pipe(fd);
    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0) {
        // Child
        close(fd[0]);
        write(fd[1], "HELLO", (strlen("HELLO")+1));
        exit(0);
    }else{
        // Parent
        close(fd[1]);
        char buffer[80];
        read(fd[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer));
        printf("Received string: %s", buffer);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

It works alright. If you comment the `write` line, the parent will report that it received a string with strange characters, which I guess is normal since it is reading memory that has nothing to do with my program.

But then, it brings on the question: isn't it possible for the parent to read the pipe ***before*** the child can write the data? If that were to happen, it would be reading weird characters.

How can the parent "wait" for the data to be written from the child?

In the future I may have several child processes, and I'd like the parent to wait for all children to be "done" with their work before moving on.

Comment: Check the value returned by **all** those system calls. You're seeing garbage because you're blindly reading from stuff that's not been written to.

Comment: @Mat: What system calls? You mean `fork()` and `pipe()`?

Comment: ... and `read` and `write`. All those can fail, and even when they don't the info returned is necessary to make a correct program in general. (There's usually not much you can do about a failed `close`, but it too can fail.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> If you comment the write line, the parent will report that it received a string with strange characters

If the call to `write` is skipped in the child, the child process ends, the child's writing end of the pipe end gets closed.

The parent detects, that the child's end of the pipe got closed, which makes the call to `read()` return. The parent actually did not read anything, so the buffer stays uninitialised and "garbage" is printed out.

Please find the relvant section from [`read`'s POSIX specification](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/read.html) below:

> When attempting to read from an empty pipe or FIFO:
>
> - If no process has the pipe open for writing, read() shall return 0 to indicate end-of-file.
>
> [...]
>
> - If  some  process  has the pipe open for writing and O_NONBLOCK is clear, read() shall block the calling thread until some data is written or the pipe is closed by all processes that had the pipe          open for writing.

To enable your code to handle the case of the child not writing anything, test whether the parent's call to 'read()` really read something:

```
            ssize_t result = read(fd[0], buffer, sizeof(buffer));
            if (-1 == result) /* Also ALWAYS test for error. */
            {
              perror("read() failed");
            }
            else if (0 == result)
            {
              fprintf(stderr, "read() returned without having read anything.\n")
            }
            else
            {
              printf("Received string: '%s'", buffer);
            }
```